# How to make true query in django_elasticsearch_dsl like icontains in django?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Need using django_elasticsearch_dsl search by given text. It should works as for full word and for only part of world. Like for "Example" and "xample". Using python 3.6, django_elasticsearch_dsl 7.0

Have found in documentation that django "icontains" query is similar to "match_phrase" in elasticsearch_dsl.query, but seems it does not work for me.

```
titles = TitleDocument.search().query(
            Q("match", title=kwargs['text']) or
            Q("match", slug=kwargs['text']) or
            Q("match", page_title=kwargs['text']) or
            Q("match_phrase", menu_title=kwargs['text']) or
            Q("match_phrase", meta_description=kwargs['text'])
 )
```

Does not work for part of word (ex. "neve", full is "never")
But Django query works good

```
ti = Title.objects.filter(meta_description__icontains=kwargs['text'])
```

Use only one field to filter by just for example

I expect to find something looks like django icontains filter. Need to find not only for full word match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with regex:

```
text = ".*{}.*".format(kwargs["text"])
titles = TitleDocument.search().query(
    "query_string",
    query=text,
    fields=["title", "slug", "page_title", "menu_title", "meta_description"],
)
```

Comment: It does not work when using regex for all words. With out regex works for full match, but does not works for part of word =(

Comment: finally found a solution after searching for hours

Comment: For full match use Q with OR condition i.e: CarDocument.search().filter(Q("regexp", name=search) | Q("match", name=search))